# Port AS3/Flex app to iPhone

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, porting

I believe Adobe tools like CS5 have ways to output as an iPhone app, but what about a regular AS3 or Flex project? Are there any tools to auto-port, or AS3/Flex iPhone implementations out there?

Out of interest, how does the CS5 thing work? Is it a totally different code-path or something less drastic? For instance Flash supports Shapes and Timelines, etc... do they in fact provide an iPhone Flash runtime of some sort?

Answer (score 2):

Packager for iPhone is what you should try out:
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/

I guess its still a beta, but doesn't hurt in trying. It also has a standalone version (without the need of CS5).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [how it works](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html), it is not a Flash runtime, but a way to compile ActionScript to native ARM assembly code, via [LLVM](http://www.llvm.org/).

Edit: also see Jesse Nicholson's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is still the flash runtime, the same way that when you export a .exe in the publish settings (not an AIR native EXE, just a projector exe). It grabs the flash VM, and your source code, compiles your source and the flash vm wrapped up together into a single executable. It's just compiled down to ARM. There is still the flash runtime running inside that executable and your bytecode is still being executed against it. So virtualization is still essentially taking place. You're right in saying it's "native" assembly code but it's a far cry from a "native" application.

Comment: So it's not doing something crazy like convert the .as3 to equivalent C++, but effectively providing a AS3->iPhone compiler.

Comment: You are certainly right that the apps created this way don't look and feel like native iPhone apps, since they don't use the Cocoa Touch framework.

Comment: I've been doing more work reverse engineering (for educational purposes) the tools Adobe uses for things like the PFI. Adobe has actually written a AS3 front end for LLVM. The actionscript compiler (asc.jar, its open source) already emits a type of intermediary bytecode, so they take this, refine/convert it to LLVM IR, then LLVM performs builtin optimization techniques on this code, and then can be send to any back end for LLVM, in this case ARM. You can learn more about this process by downloading the packager for iphone and decompiling the jar with JD-GUI. Look at GlobalOptimizer.java.

Comment: Also in regards to my last comment, again I'm not saying decompile this for illegal purposes but rather for pure educational purposes. If you don't even feel comfortable with that you can get the code for acj.jar in the flex repo. Although it will not have the LLVMEmitter and associated classes you can still see how the open source actionscript compiler uses the GlobalOptimizer class to output actionscript bytecode operations in an intermediary language (cant remember the name). http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/sandbox/asc-redux/src/java/adobe/abc/GlobalOptimizer.java